# Hockey App - User Metrics stopped working (iOS and Android)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, hockeyapp

I have two HockeyApp apps:

1 for iOS (Store)
1 for Android (Store)

When I first created them a month ago everything was working OK, the user metrics and the custom events were there. Currently none of the information is being logged to Hockey App and I can't see why.

For some reason, only the crashes are being logged. Please see the image below:

[image]

I can't see the reason, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: Yes the apps are being used currently.

Comment: Please contact HockeyApp support at https://support.hockeyapp.net and provide your specific App IDs

Comment: Thanks @LukasSpieß, I just sent an email to support@hockeyapp.net with the details. Do you recommend creating a discussion for this?

Comment: No, the email is fine. Both end up in the same place anyway :)